# TFS 2013 Build isn't triggering a WebDeploy

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs, webdeploy

I'm successfully deploying a Web site from Visual Studio using a publish profile, but once I try to configure it in a TFS build definition, it's never published.

These are the MSBuild arguments so far: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Doc.Development /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`.

Also, I'm using `GitTemplate.12.0.xaml` process template on my build definition.

Do I need to provide any further argument to MSBuild?

*Note: TFS 2013 is updated to Update 4*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also use /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true  along with /p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Doc.Development /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0

Comment: Could it be that with TFS 2012 `DeployOnBuild` was enough?

Comment: use /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true

Comment: Yeah yeah, but I mean that I remember that I didn't need this on previous TFS versions...